# Issue with dependencies running python file on another PC

Tags: command-line, pip

- I have a python file running perfectly in the IDE.
- I want to run it on a different PC without any IDE.
- I run the program from the command line: python program.py
- Error message:   File "program.py", line 8, in 
  from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
  ModuleNotFoundError: **No module named 'mpl_finance'**
- When trying: pip install mpl_finance (or pip install mpl_toolkits)
- I get the message: **No matching distribution found for mpl_finance** (or mpl_toolkits)
- There also seems to be a problem with matplotlib backend.

Looking for a solution please.

Comment: Where from have you goy that `mpl_finance` on the first PC?

Comment: @phd I think PyCharm added it when I clicked on the word underlined in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After many failed paths, here's what worked:**

- matplotlib.finance is deprecated and it is now mpl_finance.
- Create 2 files named mpl_finance.py and setup.py and get their contents from [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance).
- Then from the command-line: `python setup.py install`

**Fixing the backend (this can save you a few days):**

- If the backend of matplotlib was set in a file original PC (and not in the code). Then you need to do the same on the second PC.
- Windows Path: C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc
- Change (probably line 38) to this: `backend : Qt5Agg`